# Ubuntu Desktop reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, reinstall

Is there a way to completely wipe out a current running version of Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 on a machine without having to do the process of burning an ISO image onto a USB drive with Etcher as mentioned [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview)?

Curious if there is anyway to do a fresh start without the Etcher process burning/flasking an image to a USB drive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ubuntu is running from a partition on the HDD, then at least that partition will have some files locked. This would be true for almost any OS, such as Windows, as well. For that reason, the only effective way to **completely** wipe the HDD, prior to reinstallation, is to run the OS from other media, e.g. external USB or CD.

However, the process of creating a boot CD or USB drive is trivial, and does not require Ubuntu. You might use [Runtime Live](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-live-cd.htm), using Knoppix, [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/), based on WinPE/WinRE, or any other bootable media that contains disk partitioning software.

If you're not too worried about PII or sensitive data, the quickest way to wipe the disk is to repartition it... but forensic tools could possibly recover some data. To **completely** wipe a disk, use software that repeatedly overwrites *every* byte, e.g. [Aomei Partition Assistant](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/completely-wipe-a-hard-drive-including-os-1984.html) and [DBAN or Blancco Drive Eraser](https://dban.org/) -- a *very* lengthy process.